# Is there a 'generic we' in English?

Tags: grammaticality

Some languages around the world use the *generic we* instead of English's preferred *one* or *you*. I have noticed that some people, when asking questions on this site (EL&U although the same principle applies to ELL), use '*we*' in this generic way.

For example:

- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/231014/how-do-we-say-hexadecimal-numbers
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155057/why-do-we-say-that-we-observe-traditions
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29552/how-do-we-pronounce-others
- https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16410/why-do-we-say-wearing-perfumes

See [more](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=can+we) and [more](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=do+we)

More specifically, is it ever possible to use '*we*' when talking about a group to which one does not belong?

My instinct is to use *you* or even *one* here to form *How does one pronounce...* etc.

I can only think that it is either a transatlantic difference or a feature that has come from other languages, since the only [other uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/We) of '*we*' I could find are inappropriate.

Is my instinct right, or is this acceptable grammar?

Comment: We're fine with it.

Comment: You may be, but I don't think you can use it like that.

Comment: I would also associate it with the speech of a primary school teacher or the writing of an academic paper (*author's we* in your link), aiming to be inclusive but perhaps sometimes coming across as marginally patronising.  So its use is not grammatically wrong, but it may not always have the desired effect

Comment: The Cambridge DIctionnary doesn't see a problem with it http://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/grammaire/grammaire-britannique/pronouns-one-you-we-they   it may sound more snob because "we" is also found as Royal We ,see the various incarnation of Nosism (yeah that's what using We as generic is called) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosism

Comment: I personally don't think it should be used as a generic pronoun, but rather when it is understood you are talking about people in a specific group. But is we are starting to use and understand it that way, it is by definition grammatical—please remember that the general philosophy among English linguists is a descriptive (not prescriptive) one.

Comment: FWIW, it's idiomatic to say "how do *you* ..." and "why do *we* ..."  I can't tell you why, just that it sounds "right" to my 50-plus-year-old Midwest US ears. :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez Interesting, to my British ears, *why do we* sounds strange. Perhaps it *is* a Transatlantic thing.

Comment: We wouldn't normally ask questions like *How do we spell archaeologist?* simply because ***we*** there probably doesn't include the speaker - he *doesn't* spell it at all, because he doesn't (yet) know how to.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey: *Why do we close our eyes when we sneeze?* Do you think *that's* a "strange" way of putting it? Okay, academically it's usually *Hitler is seen as a bad person* because they like the passive, but I'm good with *We see Hitler as a bad person*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, very true. My point still stands in that it still seems strange to use *we* when referring to *you* - as in your example of *How do we spell archaeologist?*

Comment: @Kristina Lopez: I bet if you stop and think about it, you probably wouldn't use "why do we ..." if you knew very well that *you **personally** don't ...*

Comment: You seem to have missed the "Who's this 'we'?" (or it might have been the white-man quip) come-back to one particular ELU question beginning "Why do we ...".

Comment: You're right, @FumbleFingers, I probably would use "why do people...?"

Comment: 'Why do we ...?' is grammatically and idiomatically acceptable, but I'd say patronising/inaccurate to the point of unacceptability on issues where even 10% of the population addressed (and who decides _that_?) are not part of the true we-do-this-set. It should only be used for issues as non-contentious as 'Why do we drive on the left in the UK?'

Comment: There's also a sort of first person imperative: *Now let's calm down.*

Comment: Apropos of this litany of never ending comments, Queen Vic might have remarked, "We are not amused".

Comment: *[I]s it ever possible to use 'we' when talking about a group to which one does not belong?* Yes. I think of this as the "exclusive-" or "nursing we"—it pops up (at least in fiction) on the lips of medical personnel and other carers saying things like *And have **we** pooped yet today?* or *I see **we** don't like **our** vegetables* when it clearly is only the patient's bowels or appetite under discussion. There is also a "hypocritical we", as in ***We** must all tighten our belts (except for me, as I've been embezzling from y'all for years)*. Cont...

Comment: ... Note that these are very different from the "over-inclusive we" or "royal we", which is more like imputing one's own bowels or appetite to others: *why do **we** love to eat chocolate covered grubs and nasturtiums?* In that case, the speaker is included in the *we*, but the listener(s) may well not be. All of these non-standard uses of *we* are likely to be annoying to listeners to varying degrees, but I don't see anything ungrammatical about them. (These aren't formal terms, so far as I know, just my own way of thinking about unusual uses of *we* when I encounter them.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, done. Hope that clears up the confusion

Comment: @1006a If you want to answer the question, there is a if button. :)

Answer (score 2):

> When we ....

is a rhetorical ploy found in contexts as wide-ranging as philosophical treatises (*What does it mean when we say a man is noble?*) to chemistry textbooks (*When we mix oxygen and hydrogen...*) to websites about  health issues (*What should we do when we're constipated?*)

Comment: Sounds good, do you have any references?

Comment: Not sure what "references" you need. **We** has been used in a GAZILLION places for hundreds of years in this way, and your "instinct" that it is somehow ungrammatical is wrong. But for starters: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22when%20we%20say%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1672,cd_max:1867&lr=lang_en

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned; as was referenced in the comments, *we say* when used by a group including oneself, is fine; what is being questioned is whether it can be used as a replacement for *you*: can you say *we* when referring to a group to which one does not belong?

Comment: Yes.  Compare the constipation example above.  We = people. If that still doesn't satisfy you, you'll have to visit et.stackexchange.com